# Major difference between High Sierra and Mojave

Tags: macos, high-sierra, mojave

I have a MacBook Pro (2017) that have macOS High Sierra installed. Since Apple is going to release macOS Big Sur soon, the support (updates) for macOS High Sierra will end soon. What are the major difference between macOS High Sierra and macOS Mojave?

More specifically, what (major) bugs are introduced? What (major) bugs are fixed?

Comment: There are number of significant bugs in PDFKit in High Sierra, which have been fixed in Mojave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the major news in Mojave are:

- Dark mode
- Home app
- News app
- Stocks app
- Voice Memo app
- New screenshot utility
- Group FaceTime
- Desktop stacks
- Finder Quick Actions
- Continuity Camera
- Privacy enhancements
- Warnings when running 32-bit apps

It is not my impression that macOS Mojave brings along major bugs that haunt most of its users.

Comment: ...unlike Catalina, which I wish I had skipped completely.